# The drop-down menu seems to report a wrong reputation increase

Tags: support, reputation

My drop-down menu reports that my reputation increased by 5.

[image: screenshot]

When I click on 5, I am taken to the following page.

[image: screenshot]

Both the votes are votes on answers.

How can my reputation be increased of 5 points, when two of my answers have been up-voted once?

Comment: 13 hours ago means at 7:48 AM my time. I say that in the case somebody was going to say that who up-voted my answer started to up-vote it before midnight UTC, and completed the up-vote after midnight UTC. `;-)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Someone withdrew a question upvote, meaning +10 + -5 = +5. Vote withdrawals are not reflected in the dropdown itemization but are recorded in the daily/weekly/monthly summaries.

Comment: Don't you mean someone "unaccepted an answer"?